# iOs push notification compatible with PHP 5.2 or less

Tags: php, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I implemented push notifications using APNS-PHP http://code.google.com/p/apns-php/ on my server. I now have to move it to a server that has php  5.2.17  and I sadly found out that apns-php  does not support php versions lower than 5.3.

Is there any way of implementing php push notifications without updating the server (witch is out of the question)?

In other words Is there any other api that can work with older PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hy, tanks for the answer but the problem was not the APN server was the script hosting server and I found a solution for that in the mean time. I made the simplest script possible and it worked. I used the php code found in this tutorial http://blog.boxedice.com/2009/07/10/how-to-build-an-apple-push-notification-provider-server-tutorial/. turned it into a class and I that was it. It is the best script for low versions servers, but I don't know how will it handle big requests or if it will be able to deliver all messages.
Cheers
Bogdan.

Comment: Be warned that if you do keep opening and closing connections then Apple can treat it as a DOS attack!

Comment: Thank you. I adapted the tutorial so that it will open the connection send all the push messages and then close. What you say will happen only if the admin will send many messages, which in my case will not happen. Is there a better way that can work on php 5.0? I saw a method where a php service handler is launched on the server that starts opens the connections when it is needed and if it stays idle for a time it shuts down but i couldn't make it work so I used the above tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at UrbanAirship. Allows sending of a million messages a month free and no hassle creating your own server!